# Declared Boolean as False, turns up true (FIXED)

Tags: java, math, boolean

Here's a snippet from my code...

```
Boolean Add;
Double Answer;

Add = false;

if (Add == true);
{
Answer = (3 + 6);
System.out.print(Answer);
}
```

What baffles me is that at the end of my code it keeps evaluating and printing 3 + 6 even though the code is specifically geared to make it NOT show up. Any help would be appreciated.

EDIT: Thanks everyone

Comment: @Bill: MS Turbo Borland C#++

Answer (score 6):

You have a semicolon at the end of your `if` condition.  Java will treat *that* as the body for your `if` condition.  The block with braces below it is detached from the `if` condition and will always run.

Remove the semicolon, and Java will interpret the block with braces as the body for your `if` statement.

Change

```
if (Add == true);
```

to

```
if (Add == true)  // no semicolon
```

Additionally, `Add` is already a boolean value (a `Boolean` unboxed to a `boolean`).  You can just say:

```
if (Add)
```

Answer (score 5):

Remove `;` after `if` condition.

```
if (Add == true);//<-here
```

If you format this code you will get

```
if (Add == true)
    ;
```

which is the same as placing empty block after `if`

```
if (Add == true)
{}//empty block
```

so this block will always execute because it is not actually no longer related to `if` condition

```
{
    Answer = (3 + 6);
    System.out.print(Answer);
}
```

---

BTW `== true` part is redundant in condition. You can just write it as `if (Add)`

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing primitive types with reference types (not a problem really, but a bad practice nevertheless), and more importantly, there's an extra semicolon after the condition!. Try this:

```
boolean add;
double answer;

add = false;

if (add == true) // remove the ; from here
{
    answer = 3 + 6;
    System.out.print(answer);
}
```

That seemingly inoffensive `;` was the cause of the problem. If you add a `;` after the condition, you're stating: here's the end of the condition, there won't be any instructions inside. The rest of the code, the part that's inside `{}` runs inside a block, but will always be executed - it's outside the `if` statement.

Answer (score -1):

You have a semicolon immediately after `if` so it is not executed. Change:

```
if (Add == true);
```

to:

```
if (Add == true)
```

Also you should consider using `boolean` primitive instead of `Boolean` class.